# how to select any file and upload in cordova hybrid mobile app

Tags: android, cordova

I am creating a mobile app using cordova phonegap and visualstudio.
My question is: Is there any way a user of the app can select any file(not only images) from the mobile device and upload.

I am trying to use the file-transfer plugin and the input file tag for the user to select the file. When i click on the the file i can select only image files.
Also i get an error related to the fileURI
*URI not supported by CordovaResourceApi*

Till now my code is:

```
function uploadmsg() {
            try {
                var fileURI;
                fileURI = $('#fli').val();
                console.log(fileURI);
                var win = function (r) {
                  console.log('Uploaded');
                }

                var fail = function (error) {
                    console.log(error);                        
                }

                var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                options.fileKey = "file";
                options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                options.mimeType = document.getElementById('fli').files[0].type;

                var postData = $('#frmim').serialize();
                options.params = '{' + postData + '}'; // if we need to send parameters to the server request
                var ft = new FileTransfer();

                ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://someurl"), win, fail, options);

            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: search for "file picker" of "file chooser" plugins. I have provided links on other questions, but most of them were deleted by moderators

Comment: Thanks @jcesarmobile for the info, i was using wrong keywords to search :) .